# How to create install file for a Web Dynamic project Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, sql-server-ce, installation

What's the best way to create/generate a *setup* file `(.EXE)`  for a web dynamic project from *Eclipse* ?
the project must be installed after installing `tomcat & SqlCE` silently, since it depends on them both to work
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many custom exe packers are available on web.

Just google for some *"jar to exe"* or *"setup maker"* type things you would definitely find something.

Something like [this](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/).

Answer (score 0):

Java has no support for exe files. Exe files are specific to Windows platform while Java is intented to be platform independent.

Eclipse for Java doesn't offer builtin facilities to generate exe files since they have absolutely nothing to do with Java. Java's way is an executabele JAR file. You could create an executabele JAR file wherein you do the installing job in a `main()` method. Once you have the `main()` method finished, Eclipse can autogenerate the JAR by the *Runnable JAR* wizard.

If you *really* want an exe file, you'd need to write a custom one using C++ or C# (at least, the same language as Windows is written in and natively supports). It should then do basically the same as what you would do in the Java's `main()` method.